# Jquery jrumble demo 19

Tags: jquery

I'm using jrumble demo 19 and was wondering if there was a way to force it to play when it finished loading the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle').jrumble();
var demoTimeout;
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
    $this.trigger('startRumble');
    demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$this.trigger('stopRumble');}, 8000)
});
demoStart();`
```

I have tried .ready() but its not wanting to work with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should handle what you are looking for. It puts the start of the rumble and the setTimeout into a function called `rumble()`, then it gets called when the page loads, and it gets called when the element is clicked.

**[View Demo and Full Code](http://jsfiddle.net/2QKC3/)**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

    var $toggle = $('#toggle'),
        demoTimeout;

    $toggle.jrumble()

    function rumble() {
        clearTimeout(demoTimeout);
        $toggle.trigger('startRumble');
        demoTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $toggle.trigger('stopRumble');
        }, 8000);
    }

    $('#toggle').on('click', rumble);
    rumble();

});
```